# How do I PInvoke SHQueryUserNotificationState for use in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, pinvoke

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public enum QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE {
        QUNS_NOT_PRESENT = 1,
        QUNS_BUSY = 2,
        QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN = 3,
        QUNS_PRESENTATION_MODE = 4,
        QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS = 5,
        QUNS_QUIET_TIME = 6
    };
public class UserWindows {
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern int SHQueryUserNotificationState(out QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE pquns);
}
"@;

$state = [UserWindows]::QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE
[UserWindows]::SHQueryUserNotificationState([ref]$state)
```

I've tried a few different ways, just can't seem to get it working completely right.
This is the exception I'm getting now.

```
Exception calling "SHQueryUserNotificationState" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot 
convert null to type "QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE" due to enumeration values that 
are not valid. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The 
possible enumeration values are "QUNS_NOT_PRESENT,QUNS_BUSY,QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCRE
EN,QUNS_PRESENTATION_MODE,QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS,QUNS_QUIET_TIME"."
At D:\pintest.ps1:20 char:1
+ [UserWindows]::SHQueryUserNotificationState([ref]$state)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSInvalidCastException
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the enum reference to `SHQueryUserNotificationState` so that it will point to a specific member of `QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE`

For reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shqueryusernotificationstate

Comment: Try to specify ref instead of out in the C# DllImport part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The P/Invoke definition is correct.

Call it like this:

```sh
$state = [QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE]::QUNS_NOT_PRESENT
$hresult = [UserWindows]::SHQueryUserNotificationState([ref]$state)
if( $hresult -ge 0 ) {
    # HRESULT >= 0 indicates success
    "User notification state: $state"
}
else {
    # HRESULT < 0 indicates failure
    "Could not query user notification state (HRESULT: $hresult)"
}
```

Possible output:

```text
User notification state: QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS
```

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. 
I'm trying to to understand why you need to specify one of the enumeration values. When I did this in C# you didn't need to, it was `var result = SHQueryUserNotificationState(out state);`

Comment: @arock That's because PowerShell needs to know the data type of the `$state` variable. If you would use a type constraint in front of the variable without initializing it like `[QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE] $state`, then PowerShell would complain that the value of the variable does not equal one of the enumeration values.

Comment: @arock In C# you can have uninitialized enum variables, that's the difference.